# "lecture for a course" or "lecture of a course", which expression is more common?

Tags: word-usage

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE)

> Hello everyone. Welcome to the second lecture for CS230.

"the second lecture for CS230" or "the second lecture of CS230", which expression is more common?

please provide a authoritative link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have subtly different meanings, although they end up with the same practical result:

> The second lecture ***of*** a course.

This means the second lecture that *belongs to* a course or that is *part of* a course.

> The second lecture ***for*** a course.

This means that it's a lecture that is being used *for the purpose* of the course or *in order to benefit* the course.

---

There is a lot of overlap between the two—and one doesn't necessarily exclude the other. In fact, normally both are true at the same time.

As an example, I could be the instructor of a course, and I have several lectures that I give to students myself. I also plan a field trip one day somewhere else, where the students will listen to somebody else.

In theory, I could say that all of the lectures I give are ***of*** the course, but the one lecture given by somebody else, somewhere else, is not actually *of* the course but instead simply ***for*** the course. (The other lecture belongs to something different.)

But even if you make that subtle distinction, the final result is the same. In both cases, they are lectures heard by the students.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they were both about as common as one another and can be used interchangeably in this instance.